# Covering map, end points of two paths equal criterion

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was reading a proof of the following lemma:

> $\textbf{Lemma}$: Let $p\colon X \to B$ be a covering map and let $\gamma, \gamma'$ be two paths in $X$ beginning at $x_0$. Let $u=p\gamma$ and $u'=p\gamma'$. Then $\gamma(1)=\gamma'(1)$ if and only if $u(1)=u'(1)$ and $[u'^{-1}u]$ is contained in $p_\ast\pi_1(X,x)$.

I am having trouble understanding one step in the proof.

$\textit{Proof}$: We lift $u'^{-1}u$ with initial point $x_0$. Since $[u'^{-1}u] \in p_\ast \pi_1(X,x_0)$, there exists a loop which is homotopic to $u'^{-1}u$ (say via $H$), and which has a lifting with initial point $x$. $u'^{-1}u$ itself has a lifting as a loop. 
$\textbf{Therefore}$ $u$ and $u'$ have liftings with initial point $x_0$ and $\textbf{the same end point}$.

I don't understand how the last sentence follows. Let $\delta$ be a lifting of $u'^{-1}u$. Then defining $\tilde{u}(s):=\delta(s/2)$ and $\tilde{u'}(s):=\delta((s+1)/2)$ gives liftings of $u$ and $u'$, but how do I see that $\delta(1/2)=\delta(1)$? I guess I have to lift the homotopy $H$ with respect to $\delta$ but I don't know how to go on. Could someone please provide the missing details?

Note that the way the composition is written means to first go the path on the right and then the one on the left.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to get $\delta (1/2)=\delta(1)$. Note $s\mapsto \delta(\frac{s+1}{2})$ is a lift of $u')^{-1}$, not $u'$. Indeed $u$ and $u'$ are not required to lie in $p_*(\pi_1 (X,x))$.

Comment: @cjackal Thanks for your comment. So, I need to consider $s \mapsto \delta((2-s)/2)$ which makes it obvious that the endpoints of the liftings of $u$ and $u'$ are equal. But where do I have to use the homotopy $H$ then?

Comment: Then the two map $\tilde{u}$ and $\tilde{(u')^{-1}}$ have the same endpoints $\tilde{u}(1)=\tilde{(u')^{-1}}(1)=\delta(1/2)$ and $\tilde{u}(0)=\delta(0)=\delta(1)=\tilde{(u')^{-1}}(0)$.

Comment: @cjackal We have $\tilde{u}(0)=\delta(0)=\gamma(0)=x_0$ and similarly for $\tilde{u'}^{-1}$. But by the uniqueness of lifts, it follows that $\gamma=\tilde{u}$ and $\gamma'=\tilde{u'}^{-1}$. And since $\tilde{u}$ and $\tilde{u'}^{-1}$ have the same end points, the same is true for the gammas. Still I do not see where we used that $[u'^{-1}u]\in p_\ast \pi_1(X,x_0)$.

Comment: You have to use it to gaurantee $\delta$ is a loop. As $\delta$ is a loop based at $x_0$ lifting ${u′}^{−1}u$, (a representative of the homotopy class of) the two lifting $\tilde{u}$ and $\tilde{u'}$ of $u$ and $u'$ is just $s\mapsto \delta(s/2)$ and $s\mapsto \delta(\frac{2-s}{2})$

Comment: @cjackal Thanks, I got it now. We can lift $H$ wrt $\delta$ and some $\omega \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$ which satisfies $p_\ast([\omega])=[u'^{-1}u]$. Both lifts coincide at the point $(0,0)$ with value $x_0$, hence they must be equal. It follows $\delta(0)=\delta(1)$. Now, this implies that the liftings $\tilde{u}$ and $\tilde{u'}$ of $u$ and $u'$ start at the same point as the gammas, namely at $x_0$. Hence $\tilde{u}=\gamma$ and $\tilde{u'}=\gamma'$.

Comment: Cool. The part that shows $\delta$ is a loop is often referred as homotopy lifting lemma in literature.